# Align two buttons vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a backend developer so please excuse the weak code you might find,

this is how my form looks like :

[these two buttons are not correctly aligned in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MbeK.png)

I am having this issue only in Chrome , FireFox & Edge are working as expected see image below

[How i want the form to look like ( shot from FF )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVfgK.png)

the Form Code :

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 100px;">
        <div class="card card-outlined style-primary-dark" style="width: 80%">
            <div class="card-head">
                <header><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i> QR Code</header>
            </div><!--end .card-head -->
            <div class="card-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtData" style="color:#0d998f;" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Texte à Crypté</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtData" placeholder="Saisir vos données...." required>
                        </div><br><br><br>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 navigator">
                            <button id="btGenerer" type="button" class="btn ink-reaction btn-primary">Générer</button>
                            <button id="btSaveQR" type="button" class="btn ink-reaction btn-default-dark">Sauvegarder</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div><!--end .card-body -->
        </div><!--end .card -->
    </div><!--end .col -->
```

some CSS simply for FF & Edge

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
    {
        .navigator {
            margin-left:37%;
        }
    }

    @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
        .navigator {
            margin-left:37%;
        }
    }
```

When Inspecting the page on Chrome the ( Générer ) button seems to take a lot of space maybe it is what's causing the deformity , see image below

[Générer Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTtac.png)

[Sauvegarder Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa3fn.png)

Comment: Can you share your CSS too?

Comment: I don't understand, your code works fine, i just tested in chrome.

Comment: the CSS is from a template i downloaded , i think that's what is causing the issue

Comment: Added an answer, hope that will help.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @geodiaz : Version 66.0.3359.139

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the browser specific CSS and add the following CSS:

```css
.navigator{
  text-align: center;
}
.navigator button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #20252b;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button#btGenerer{
  background: #0aa89e;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 100px;">
        <div class="card card-outlined style-primary-dark" style="width: 80%">
            <div class="card-head">
                <header><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i> QR Code</header>
            </div><!--end .card-head -->
            <div class="card-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtData" style="color:#0d998f;" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Texte à Crypté</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtData" placeholder="Saisir vos données...." required>
                        </div><br><br><br>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 navigator">
                            <button id="btGenerer" type="button" class="btn ink-reaction btn-primary">Générer</button>
                            <button id="btSaveQR" type="button" class="btn ink-reaction btn-default-dark">Sauvegarder</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div><!--end .card-body -->
        </div><!--end .card -->
    </div><!--end .col -->
```

You can also check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sy89qh73/

Comment: i really like your answer but still same result on chrome , check the updated question it might clear some stuff

Comment: This CSS works with your current HTML. Can you upload a reproducible snippet?

Comment: @goediaz, Without out any working snippet, it's hard to reproduce. But I'm sure there are some top margin/padding or some browser specific CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox to align them. this will help vertically and horizontally.

```
.navigator{
  display:flex; 
  align-items:center; 
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/odecLzad/

Comment: still the same issue on Chrome,